# Accessing properties of object in SelectList in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, selectlist

I'm a newbie here. I'm trying to create a dropdown list (`SelectList`) which would display the location of shops in my ASP.NET MVC application.

The `Shop` class has a `Location` property which in turn has a `Name` property:

```
public class Shop
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The `Name` property is a string.

I tried to use this code:

```
var shops = _applicationDbContext.Shops
                                 .Include(x => x.Location).ToList();

var mwc = new Create
              {
                   ShopSL = new SelectList(shops, nameof(Shop.Id), nameof(Shop.Location.Name)) 
              };
```

But I get an error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

If I remove the `Shop.Location.Name` and change it to `Shop.Location` only, the dropdown list displays the object instead, something like `Namespace.Data.Location`.

I would like the dropdown list to be able to display the name of the location.

Could someone point me to the right direction please? Thank you.

Comment: Please post you Shop class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var shops = _applicationDbContext.Shops
                    .Select (i=> new 
                    {
                     Id=i.Id
                     Name=i.Location.Name
                     }).ToList();

var mwc = new Create
              {
                   ShopSL = new SelectList(shops,"Id","Name") ;
              };
```

Comment: Yes it works, 
I re-edit the last part of your code a bit into
```
 ShopSL = new SelectList(shops,"Id","Name") ;
```


Thank you